# Backend validation fail throws "CORS policy" error

Tags: reactjs, laravel, validation, cors

I am working on a user registration feature with frontend React and backend Laravel 8. When the input fields are valid it is working fine. But even if any of the input fields fail in the backend validation it throws an error saying "access has been blocked by CORS policy". [Here is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l1hG.png). My question is why is everything working fine when the input fields are valid, but throwing an unrelatable error when it fails. And below is my code:

Frontend (React)

```
const register = async(values) => {

        const {email, serial, password, confirm_password} = values;

        const details = {email : email, serial : serial, password: password, password_confirmation : confirm_password};

        try {

            const result = await fetch('http://192.168.1.15:8000/api/v1/register', {
                method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(details),
            })

            const data = await result.json();

            if (data.error) {
                
                console.log(data.error)
            }
            else {
                setUser(data.data)
                cookies.set('Noortap', data.data, { path: '/' });
                console.log(cookies.get('Noortap'))
            }


        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }

    }
```

Backend (Laravel)

```
  public function register(Request $request)
    {
        

         $request->validate([
            'name' => 'max:255',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users,email|email|max:255',
            'serial' => ['required','max:255', new IsValidSerialNumber],
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',

         ]);
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'is_admin' => 0,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);

        \App\Models\Tag::where('serial_number', $request->serial)->update([
            'assigned' => 1,
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);

        // // response
        //  return $this->login($request);
        return $request;

    }
```

Comment: CORS headers are added on the response however a validation exception will prevent the middleware that adds them from running. It's probably not a major problem.

Answer (score -1):

That is because your frontend and backend are on separate "domains". In this case, they are on the same domain but a different port. You will need to add `http://192.168.1.15:3000` to the `$except` array in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` so that you dont face a CORS policy issue.

So your file should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        '192.168.1.15:3000'
    ];
}
```